# Strong induction - verify solution of llinear recurrence is powers of 2

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I've got this mathematical problem:

Consider the sequence $\{a_n\}$ defined by

$a_n= \begin{cases} n, & \text{if } 1\leq n\leq 2 \\
                      a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}                                    & \text{if } n\geq 3      %
        \end{cases}$

Prove by induction that $a_n=2^{n-1}$, for all $n\geq 1$.

I can tell that I've tried base case: $n=1$ and $n=2$ which is $1$ and $2$. But strong induction is not the best for me, can someone explain in details how I can solve this and similar problems in the future? Thanks!

Comment: **Hint:** $2^{n-2}+2\cdot 2^{n-3} = 2^{n-2}+2^{n-2} = 2^{n-1}$

Comment: Ahh you say $a_{n-1}=2^{n-1-1}=2^{n-2}$ and $a_{n-2}=2^{n-1-2}=2^{n-3}$ and then use $a_{n-1}+2a_{n-2}$ but we already know what $a_{n-1}$ and   $a_{n-2}$ is. And therefore you get your answer?

Comment: @AndersJørgensen. As a native Danish speaker you are in a unique position to enjoy Ebbe Thue Poulsen's book "Funktioner af en of flere variable". It is officially out of print, but the Department of Mathematics at Aarhus has made a softcover version which you can get through Stakbogladen. In Denmark, it is $the$ book to read if you want to write clear proofs. Send me an email and I can give you the exact contact info.

Comment: @CarlChristian thank you. Can you send me the information to my mail? It's anjoe17@student.sdu.dk because I'm new on this website and I could not find you email. Thank you.

Comment: I made a modest change to the definition of the set $V$ to allow for a more "mechanical" (for lack of a better word) application of the principle of mathematical induction.

Answer (score 1):

Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and suppose that $a_k=2^{k-1}$ when $k\leqslant n$; you want to prove that $a_{n+1}=2^n$. But$$a_{^n+1}=a_n+2a_{n-1}=2^{n-1}+2\times2^{n-2}=2\times2^{n-1}=2^n.$$

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is to write a proof by induction in a manner which can not be faulted by even the most critical readers. To that end I recommend the following approach.

Let $V \subseteq \mathbb N$ be given by
$$ V = \{ n \in \mathbb N \: : \: a_k = 2^{k-1}, \: \text{for $k = 1,2,\dotsc, n$} \}.$$
We must show that $V = \mathbb N$. By manual inspection, we find $1 \in V$ and $2\in V$. Now assume that $n \in V$ and $n>1$. We claim that $n+1 \in V$. Since $n \in V$ it suffices to show that $a_{n+1} = 2^n$. Since $n+1 > 2$ we have 
$$ a_{n+1} = a_n + 2 a_{n-1}.$$ Since $n \in V$ by assumption, we know $a_n = 2^{n-1}$ and $a_{n-1} = 2^{n-2}$ and we can deduce $$a_{n+1} = 2^{n-1} + 2 \cdot 2^{n-2} = 2^n,$$ which implies $n+1 \in V$. By the principle of mathematical induction, we conclude that $V = \mathbb N$.